# Regular expression for Password rule

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a weird requirement for setting up a password rule.. :|
My requirement is to set a password rule to allow only uppercase letters and the min.password length is 5, max password lenght is 8. I used the following expression accordingly..

`^(?=.*[A-Z]).{5,8}$`

But, It does not work that way. Later, I came to know that the [A-Z] doesn't mean that only upper case letters are allowed, it means that atleast one should be an upper case.
It works fine with the range{5,8}, kindly guide me in completing the other requirement for allowing only upper case letters..
Can we try setting up negation for all the other things? If so, then do let me know the way to write a negation?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: That's a pretty bad password rule.

Comment: hehe.. ya, but that was our requirement(a weird one ;) ).. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following sounds like the simplest implementation of what you describe:

```
^[A-Z]{5,8}$
```

I'm not sure why you would need anything like `(?=...)` which is a "zero-width positive lookahead". Just match the string, nothing tricky.

Comment: Good answer, but why did you change the quantifier? It should have a comma and not a dash => `^[A-Z]{5,8}$`

Comment: @stema: I suppose that depends on your dialect of regular expression engine. I'll change it to comma for consistency.

Comment: Just out of interest, which dialect does use a dash? I have never seen it.

Comment: @stema: I don't recall at the moment. I'm pretty sure I used one where comma meant "this or that" (and you could have more than two choices) and dash was a range.

Answer (score 2):

The rule should be something like this:

```
^(?=[A-Z]{5-8}$)
```

It means: 5-8 `A-Z` letters followed by end-of-string. Note that I have put the $ IN the `()`, so that you can add other rules/consume the string

```
^(?=[A-Z]{5-8}$)(?!A+$)
```

For example this is the same plus an exclusion rule of "only A" so no `AAAAA`, `AAAAAA`...

Comment: Thanq.. that improved my understaning.. :D